# Firestore : problem while removing item from array of maps

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What is the way to remove an item in an index from array of map in firestore?

I have an array of maps as in the picture I attached, I need to delete an index of array 'cart'.

I tried arrayRemove() but its not working.[image]

Comment: can you share some code? like this admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({ count:'3', item_id:'123' })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete an array item using its index. This is intentional because, there may be multiple clients adding/removing the items in the array, which will change the indexes. Hence, you must delete the items by values. More details [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html).

Furthermore, if you need conditional delete, like "delete all items with count 1", then you need to handle this case yourself, on the client side as: get the array, update it, push it back.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, if you can change your data structure to a map instead of an array then you can delete at a specific key.

```
cart: {
  0: {count: 3...},
  1: {count: 1...} 
}
```

Then on your client (details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields)):

```
docRef.update.{['chat.' + index]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()};
```